# Using FTP in j2me

Tags: java-me, ftp

Could any one tell me how to send files using FTP in j2me..I got this document...But it did not contain sample code:

http://ftp2me.sourceforge.net/javadoc/0.2_beta/

From this I am using below code, but not working.

```
Ftp2Me ftp = new Ftp2Me("208.109.107.26", 21, "sdsd", "sdad", "Chetan");
```

Could any one give me sample code.

Thanks..

Comment: A quick search gave me this:
http://www.opendebug.com/article/463568
and
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?204341-FTP2ME

Comment: You may wish to change your login info now that you posted username and password online for the world to see.

Comment: Thanks...for your reply.....Now I am getting write error, when I trying to connect to ftp server from nokia 2700....But working fine with emulater...what I am missing....please suggest me..Its really urgent.